# Way to get access to cookies with axios request in chrome application tab

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, axios, setcookie

I'm developing f/e page and b/e server.

f/e : react, localhost:3000

b/e : expresses, localhost:80

and I also hosted both server with different domain.

I have send a request using axis to the b/e server to get authorization cookie.
I received set-cookie header but i can't see it on my application tab.

I have searched a lot of posts.
They said that I should add an withCredentials option to axios config.
And also I need to add credentials option to b/e CORS setting.

So I fixed all of them.

But still I cannot get access to the cookies.

By the way, I cannot see or get access to the cookie. But if I send a request to B/E server, the cookies are sent correctly.

I have this issue for months.
Please help me out experts.

And please let me know if need more information.

here is my codes

```js
// expressjs
app.use(cors({
  origin: true,
  credentials: true,
}));

...
    res.cookie('SID', token, {
      httpOnly: true, secure: true, sameSite: 'None'
    });
    res.cookie('SSID', token, {
      httpOnly: false, secure: true, sameSite: 'None', path: '/'
    });
...
```

I did it with/without defaults option and also with/without inline option

```js
//react axios
...
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
...

const {status, data} = await axios.post(`${url}/api/blah`, {
  something
}, {withCredentials: 'include'});
```

[Response cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeR5r.png)
[Chrome application cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbEwp.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the right syntax for `withCredentials` on `axios` is:

```js
//react axios
//...
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
//...

const {status, data} = await axios.post(`${url}/api/blah`, {
  something
}, {withCredentials: true}); // instead of 'include'
```

I remember having an issue where `axios.defaults.withCredentiasl = true` solved it, but you probably don't want to keep it like that forever, so I'd suggest that you set it back to false after the call is finished. Also, [the issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/587) looks fixed on axios repo, so I'd try to solve it without changing the defauls.